# Duplicate Values From Previous Row For Same Subject in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Assume `df` which looks like this:

| subjectid | event | led1 | led2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD_1234 | base | 22.5 | 50.3 |
| ABCD_1234 | followup | `NA` | `NA` |
| ABCD_3456 | base | 11.2 | -23.87 |
| ABCD_3456 | followup | `NA` | `NA` |
| ZXRT_5555 | base | `NA` | -0.9 |
| ZXRT_5555 | followup | `NA` | `NA` |
| EFGH_8976 | base | `NA` | `NA` |
| EFGH_8976 | followup | `NA` | `NA` |

How can one duplicate the values in rows where event is `base` to the `followup` rows for `led1` and `led2`?

Output:

| subjectid | event | led1 | led2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD_1234 | base | 22.5 | 50.3 |
| ABCD_1234 | followup | 22.5 | 50.3 |
| ABCD_3456 | base | 11.2 | -23.87 |
| ABCD_3456 | followup | 11.2 | -23.87 |
| ZXRT_5555 | base | `NA` | -0.9 |
| ZXRT_5555 | followup | `NA` | -0.9 |
| EFGH_8976 | base | `NA` | `NA` |
| EFGH_8976 | followup | `NA` | `NA` |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` to perform operation on all columns that starts with "led". When the `event` column equals "followup" and at the same time the `led` column is `NA`, fill the `led` column with values at `event` equals "base".

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("led"), ~ifelse(event == "followup" & is.na(.x), .x[event == "base"], .x)), 
         .by = subjectid)

#>   subjectid    event led1   led2
#> 1 ABCD_1234     base 22.5  50.30
#> 2 ABCD_1234 followup 22.5  50.30
#> 3 ABCD_3456     base 11.2 -23.87
#> 4 ABCD_3456 followup 11.2 -23.87
#> 5 ZXRT_5555     base   NA  -0.90
#> 6 ZXRT_5555 followup   NA  -0.90
#> 7 EFGH_8976     base   NA     NA
#> 8 EFGH_8976 followup   NA     NA
```

Comment: @fnaber The syntax of `.by = subjectid` is introduced in `dplyr` version 1.1.0, which equals `group_by(subjectid)` as in your suggested edit. The current version is already 1.1.2, so maybe you can consider updating the package :)